# Which connection string is chosen when it is specified in web.config , in IIS Default web site and in IIS application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

There is an option to specify the Connection string in multiple places like In web.config, in IIS (Default web site and the application itself), if the connection string is specified in all these three places,  which connection string is chosen by the App?

Comment: What do you mean? The application doesn't just choose a connection string. The code has to call for it.

Comment: did you mean, which connection string will be chosen, IIS one or web.config one

Comment: if you have a connection string in web.config and open application settings in IIS-> connection strings you will see same connection from web.config.
IIS loads settings from Web.config.  So code will pick web.config connection string
in addition, some global IIS web.config settings can be overwritten by web.config.

Comment: @JeetanGupta yes

Comment: Why not try it out? It wouldn't take you long to write an app and find out.

Comment: @MattRowland, lets say you have connection sting specified on multiple places, which one is chosen?

Comment: As @Kadir wrote in his answer, there is no order. It all depends on which one is called.

Comment: If you look at the connection strings settings in IIS, it says the Entry Type. It's either local or inherited. Local when editing the site directly means that those settings are stored in the site's web.config. Inherited means they come from a higher level, such as the root web.config. You can learn about the configuration system [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7).

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with the connection strings in my application running using IIS 8.5.

- It looks like there are only two places to add connection strings: the local web.config and global web.config. IIS gives an interface to update these files.
- Duplicate keys in a web.config file or across the local and global web.config triggers is not allowed. So shouldn't have to worry about which connection is chosen. If your code calls for a key, it will find that value. If there are zero or multiple connection strings with the same key expect errors. :)

Local vs Global Web.Config - There are local web.configs for each app and a global web.config per server. The global web.config is at `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG` for me.

IIS Interface

- IIS shows a 'Connection Strings' button (button and dialog are pictured below) that brings up a menu.
- If I update a connection in the web.config file, the dialog updates. If I update from the dialog, the web.config updates. So it looks like they are kept in sync.
- Connections from the local web.config show 'Entry Type' as Local. Global web.configs connections show as Inherited
- I also tried to set the same key (eg LocalSqlServer) in both web.configs and IIS threw an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can put a connection string wherever you wish. It's *just a string*. You could put it in a JSON file, an INI file, get it from the registry, get it from a SQL database, hardcode it in your app, literally anywhere you can store a string you can store a connection string.

Answer (score -1):

There is no order, there is a name property in the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="RealDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="" />
  <add name="NorthWind" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In your code which database you want to use, you can get it from web.config and you can send it or use it on your data access layer.

```
var realConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RealDB"].ConnectionString;
var NortWindConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWind"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: You failed to address the actual question.